# How to automatically translate models of a django webapp

Tags: django, translation

I need to translate an ecommerce webapp built with Django-Oscar.
I got the system language translated, so now I'm focusing only in translating the product names, product descriptions and the categories names.

There are hundreds of products, and new ones will be added. 
So using the method where I have to manually insert translations in the .po files doesn't look like a good idea.

I am considering to use the google translation API.
I have watched a tutorial just with python.

I would like to know if this is suitable for Django? 
Will this make the app slow?

Are there better alternatives?

Success
Jaime

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you will translate with Google API every time the webpage is loaded it will be very slow or at least slower than without calling Google API... is not an efficient method.

I think the best way to do the job is write a simple script that process .po files and add translations using Google Translate API.

With this library you can manipulate .po files easily: https://bitbucket.org/izi/polib/wiki/Home

Comment: I realized that I can't use po files. since the data is loaded dynamically. I am using something like a {{ description }} template tag that is loaded for each product. For this reason I can't use the {% trans ' ' %} tag. I created a field description for each language and I am implementing a python script to fill all the fields with the translations from Google API.  To conclude: I will be checking everytime the description is evoked, what language code is selected, with {{ LANGUAGE_CODE }} and create a few IF tags to display the correct language description. You think it's efficient?